# Self-destructing feature with rake task not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rake-task

I am trying to make a feature in my to-do list application where the to-do will self destruct after 7 days.  However with my present code, the days are counting up from the date the todo was created instead of counting down and then being destroyed.  Any ideas on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Here is my todo partial in views:

```
 <tr id="<%= dom_id(todo)%>">
    <td><%= todo.description %></td>
    <td><%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(todo.created_at + 7.days) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Completed", todo, method: :delete, remote: true, class: "btn btn-success" %></td>
  </tr>
```

Here is my rake task code:

```
desc 'Removes items over a week old'
task delete_items: :environment do
  Todo.where("created_at <= ?", Time.now - 7.days).destroy_all
end
```

Here is my destroy.js.erb file:

```
<% if @todo.destroyed? %>
   $('#todo_' +<%= @todo.id %>).hide();
   $('.alert').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><%= flash[:notice] %>");
   $('.alert').addClass('alert-success');
   $('.alert').removeClass('remove');
<% else %>
   $('.alert').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><%= flash[:error] %>");
   $('.alert').addClass('alert-danger');
   $('.alert').removeClass('remove');
<% end %>
```

Here is my create.js.erb file:

```
 <% if @todo.valid? %>
   $('.js-todos').prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render(@todo)) %>");
   $('.new-todo').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'todos/form') %>");
   $('.alert').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><%= flash[:notice] %>");
   $('.alert').addClass('alert-success');
   $('.alert').removeClass('remove');
 <% else %>
   $('.alert').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><%= flash[:error] %>");
   $('.alert').addClass('alert-danger');
   $('.alert').removeClass('remove');
   $('.new-todo').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'todos/form') %>")
 <% end %>
```

Please let me know if you need to see any other files.  Thanks again!

Edit:  Added files:

Here is my schedule.rb code:

```
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"

every 1.day do
  rake "delete_items"
end
```

And here is my new deploy.rb file:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
require "whenever/capistrano"

# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.2.1'

set :application, 'my_app_name'
set :repo_url, 'git@example.com:me/my_repo.git'
```

Do I need to put fill in the set:application/set:repo_url for the deploy.rb file to work? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `7.days.ago` instead of `Time.now - 7.days` to make that rake task a smidge more readable.

Comment: Does the rake task work? That is, if you run `rake delete_items`, does it delete the items? It should. Were is the code which is running the rake task? All I see here is templates and Javascript.

Comment: Finally, `distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(todo.created_at + 7.days)` - what do you expect that to say? If I just created the todo, it should say "7 days". If I come back tomorrow, it should say "6 days". Right?

Comment: The core line in your rake task (`Todo.where("created_at <= ?", Time.now - 7.days).destroy_all`) looks correct. That should do exactly what you think it will. If it isn't working, it's likely a problem in how you're calling the rake task. You should be calling it using some sort of scheduling (and so the view code above isn't truly relevant to this behavior). You could test it by decreasing the time window and running the task explicitly, as pjmorse suggested.

Comment: I rans rake delete_items, as pjmorse suggested, and it deleted the items that were more than 7 days old, but left the item that was 2 days old, so I know that is working now.  I now remember that I used the Whenever gem for scheduling the rake task, but I didn't have a deploy.rb file set up.  So I just added the capistrano gem, which added the deploy.rb file and I did my best to set it up.  Please see my added code above.  So could I just use my same code and change 7.days to 1.minute to test it?

Comment: I just tried out my new code by switching 7.days to 1.minute to test it.  The task runs and shows "less than one min" remaining, but then after one minute is up, the to-do doesn't delete, it just restarts again at 1 minute remaining.  Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Now I ran rake delete_items again, and the items deleted.  I created a new to-do and now it's counting up instead of down again (at 3 min.now!).  I didn't change any code between this test and the last test...

Comment: When you say "it is counting up instead of down again", what do you mean by it? Your _view_ should __definitely__ be counting up, because it's representing an (increasing) distance since being created. Your cron task shouldn't necessarily be visibly counting anywhere. As long as it's running correctly (and can be scheduled correctly), then it sounds like it's working, no? Am I misunderstanding what's wrong?

Comment: I have a table column titled "Days Left", so I am wanting the days to in this column to start out at 7 days when a todo is first created.  Then it should count down to 1 day left and then get destroyed.  Instead, my app is starting at 7 days and counting up and never getting destroyed. I tried changing the + in my code to a - , but it is still counting up instead of down.

Answer (score 0):

Your table will always count up. Forget the implementation intricacies of the `distance_of_time_in_words` method and just consider what it's saying: If you create an item today, its distance in time tomorrow will be 1 day. Then 2 days on the day after tomorrow. Then 3 days. Adding 7 days to the created time will just make it -6 days, then -5 days, etc. (Ignoring how `d_o_t_i_w_f_n` formats it). When you then hit 0, the todo should be deleted, and not show up on the table, BUT the table is simply displaying things -- it has no real relation to whether an item is deleted or not; it just informs users. The deletion is taken care of by the rake task you wrote, which appears to be working **when** it's run.

It sounds like the problem is your task isn't being run at all. When you run it manually, according to your reports, it's working, but your **scheduler** is failing to run it regularly. How are you scheduling? Is the scheduler not working on both local and production environments? What tools are you using to schedule, and how are you using them?

Because your table and scheduler are separate questions, I'd suggest asking a new question about the rake scheduling failure, in which you post your scheduling code (what gems, if any are you using? How are you using them? What is the behavior of running the task explicitly (outside a scheduler) locally and on production?), and try to determine what part of scheduling the rake task is failing.

Your table seems essentially correct. If it's failing to display the desired words/numbers, that's just a function of the `distance_of_time_in_words` method, and how you're using it. Perhaps experiment with that in the Rails console:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper # Module of which d_o_t_i_w_f_n is a method
distance_of_time_in_words_from_now(5.days.ago)
distance_of_time_in_words_from_now(24.hours.from_now)
```

The fact that items that you want to be deleted are showing up in the table probably has everything to do with scheduling and nothing to do with table logic, so in that question, I'd focus on the scheduling exclusively.